# Rails App Suddenly Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I was just working on one of my models when my Rails app would not work anymore. Even typing out commands like rails -v, rails, c, bundle install, or any command is giving out the same error. What's causing it is a syntax error on the file fileutils.rb. I'm using the ruby version ruby-1.9.3-p551.

[First set of error messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA6i3.png) 
(I have not included the middle part of the error messages.)
[Last set of error messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0XMh.png)

I do not understand as to what caused the file fileutils.rb to be modified or be syntax errored.

Comment: Maybe one of your installed gems is corrupting this file?

Comment: I did not make any changes with my gems and just then I was testing the Onfido API with my app. I also did a migration by adding a column to a model but it doubt it's the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the fileutils.rb by copy-pasting lines 309-421 from another  [fileutils.rb file](https://github.com/sj26/ruby-1.9.3-p0/blob/master/lib/fileutils.rb).

I got it working again but I am still confused as to what corrupted my file.